# Android - Change package name of live application

Tags: android, eclipse, upload, google-play, apk

I have one application which is already live on google play named 'Moodlytics'.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AnantApps.Moodlytics&hl=en
Currently its package name is 'AnantApps.Moodlytics'.
(I know its not good practice to use capital letters for package name)

Now I am going to give an update to my application.

So my question is : Can I use 'anantApps.moodlytics' (all with small letters) as package name instead of the original one? Will current live application will be affected by this or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't, look here: http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html
Because the package name is an unique name of you package and android cannot determine if it belongs to your older package name. And so it treats it like if it were another app.

Comment: Even though, i am just changing uppercase to lowercase?

Comment: Yes because !"packagename".equals("pAcKaGeNAme");

Comment: please see my another question which is related to this one.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510462/android-parse-error-installation-error-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you cannot "update" your application with a different package name. The package name of an application is case sensitive. 
Once it's published, you can't do anything about it.

See : http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html