# Android parse error Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED (because of Capital letters in package name)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, apk, package-name

This question is linked with my earlier question. please see below link.

[Android - Change package name of live application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496691/android-change-package-name-of-live-application)

So now i am buiding my apk with older package name i.e.,'AnantApps.Moodlytics'.
I also have made all required changes for that.

but after that when i try to run it on device, it gives me a console error like this.

> [2013-10-22 11:26:03 - Moodlytics] Android Launch!
>
> [2013-10-22 11:26:03 - Moodlytics] adb is running normally.
>
> [2013-10-22 11:26:03 - Moodlytics] Performing Anantapps.Moodlytics.ui.ActivitySplashScreen activity launch
>
> [2013-10-22 11:26:04 - Moodlytics] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to
> detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
>
> [2013-10-22 11:26:07 - Moodlytics] Uploading Moodlytics.apk onto
> device '4E4400F02B00CE54'
>
> [2013-10-22 11:26:08 - Moodlytics] Installing Moodlytics.apk...
>
> [2013-10-22 11:26:16 - Moodlytics] Installation error:
>
> INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED [2013-10-22 11:26:16 -
>
> Moodlytics] Please check logcat output for more details. [2013-10-22
>
> 11:26:16 - Moodlytics] Launch canceled!

After that i made one apk file. but here also, it gives me an error while installing apk.

Parse Error : There was a problem parsing this package

I think this error is coming because of the capital package name.
So now, i am in very much trouble. I can't change the package name to small letters and with capital letters the code is not working.

So help me guys. what should i do? How can i give un update to my already live application on Google Play which has 'capital letters' in package name?

Comment: Google play will not allow changes in package name, once you submitted in google play.

Comment: Yes, you are right. but now i am not able to run code with the package name with Capital letters. 'Anantapps.Moodlytics'. (The Original one). SO what should I do now?

Comment: Logcat only showed that one line of `Parse Error` only?

Comment: In logcat i am getting this error :

10-22 12:11:56.224: W/ActivityManager(77): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/Moodlytics.apk

10-22 12:11:56.244: W/PackageParser(77): /data/app/vmdl1786060596.tmp (at Binary XML file line #88): <activity> does not have valid android:name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So finally i find solution. Hope it will help others who are facing this issue.

I ran project in Linux OS. In linux os, eclipse doesn't give any error for capitalised package name.

1.) I renamed package name with capital letters

2.) Then I imported appropriate R in java files. (in my case it is AnantApps.Moodlytics.R). (We can replace old R with new one easily by find/replace functionality of eclipse)

And thats it.

Main problem is that you need to have Ubuntu Linux OS for this.

Answer (score 0):

Please You should delete your `gen` folder from your workspace..After that give build project. Now You can run your application..Please try it.

Comment: are you run the app in smart phone only right. If it is, please confirm with storage of your mobile. some times will get this error for space too. so,please can u uninstall any app from your mobile and try to install this app..

Comment: I have a lot of storage available in my phone. And I also tried to run  project on emulator. but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Using Android Studio.
U must change in manifest file like that

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
```

and Also change In Gradle Script

```
Gradle Script->build.gradle(Module:app)
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "" >>//Your Package Name
        minSdkVersion 15 >>Here also give minsdkversion which is given in                        manifest file
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

[Package Parsing error solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YsuAsJi6q4)